# What horse or horses played Shadowfax?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, animals

Shadowfax is the last of an ancient breed of horses, a horse king. In the *Lord of the Rings* trilogy, what is the name of the horse or horses that were honored to play Shadowfax?

[image: Image from the LotR movie, showing Gandalf and Shadowfax]

Comment: In the extended versions of the DVDs/Blu-Rays there is an extra all about the horses used. The two horses playing Shadowfax are both included.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Ian McKellen's website](http://www.mckellen.com/cinema/lotr/001003.htm), Shadowfax was played by two horses. Blanco, mentioned in [rand al'thor's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105362/31051), was described by McKellen as Shadowfax's "galloping double."

The principal horse, however, was another Andalusian stallion named Domero (bold is my emphasis, italic is McKellen's):

> Gandalf of course isn't as sentimental as this Englishman, although I had him whispering to the chestnut Clyde who dropped him off at Bag End in the first film's opening scene. Gandalf's equine faith lies other than in the likes of Bill and Clyde. As he tells Pippin: *"Shadowfax will have no harness. You do not ride Shadowfax: he is willing to carry you - or not. If he is willing, that is enough. It is then his business to see that you remain on his back, unless you jump off into the air."* He is speaking of a marvel and Peter **Jackson has cast a white 16 year old Andalusian stallion called Domero who, standing at 16 hands is more than up to the part, at least as far as looks are concerned.** His alert ears pivot above his noble skull, his mane is thick and in no need of the false hair that some of the other horses, including Bill, wear in the film.

Unfortunately, [Domero succumbed to melanoma](http://www.horsechannel.com/horse-news/2014/04/09-equine-actor-shadowfax-euthanized.aspx) in 2003.

Comment: Ah. That'll teach me to do my research better next time rather than try to answer as fast as possible :-)

Comment: Today I learned that horses can get melanoma.

Answer (score 5):

[**Blanco**](https://www.facebook.com/Lord-of-The-Rings-Shadowfax-star-horse-Blanco-115471305137956/), a striking white Andalusian stallion.

He was [euthanised](http://www.horsechannel.com/horse-news/2014/04/09-equine-actor-shadowfax-euthanized.aspx) last year aged 25 after a long illness.

Comment: sad that he has passed on

Comment: Both links appear to be dead